# How to change read_only to read_write in vb.net sql database connection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, database-permissions

How to change read_only to read_write in vb.net SQL Server database connection?
Error message:

> Failed to update databse because the database is read_only

Comment: What database product? Ms-Sql, MySql, Ms-Access?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server database file

Comment: I guess! you have local database file (mdf). Where this file is located?

Answer (score 1):

This change will need to be made at the database server - see the article below for details:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/7925902b-9d6f-445a-8432-e58e7580d65d/

Answer (score 0):

```
exec sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, MYUSER
```